# No generator with the name mean.js installed

Tags: npm, mean-stack, meanjs, mean.io, yo

Not sure how to fix this:

```
 ~  i   master ⭑  mean  yo mean.js                                                                                               10:02:03 PM 
Error mean.js 

You don't seem to have a generator with the name mean.js installed.
You can see available generators with npm search yeoman-generator and then install them with npm install [name].
To see the 0 registered generators run yo with the `--help` option.
```

I also tried this but still no success:

```
 ~  i   master ⭑  mean  npm install -g mean                                                                                ➶ 1  10:01:18 PM 
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mean
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mean
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mean/-/mean-1.0.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mean/-/mean-1.0.0.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coveralls
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/coveralls
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/coveralls/-/coveralls-2.11.8.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/coveralls/-/coveralls-2.11.8.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/js-yaml/3.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lcov-parse/0.0.6
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request/2.67.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/log-driver/1.2.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist/1.2.0
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/request/2.67.0
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/js-yaml/3.0.1
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/log-driver/1.2.4
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/lcov-parse/0.0.6
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist/1.2.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist/-/minimist-1.2.0.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request/-/request-2.67.0.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/js-yaml/-/js-yaml-3.0.1.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/log-driver/-/log-driver-1.2.4.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lcov-parse/-/lcov-parse-0.0.6.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist/-/minimist-1.2.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/lcov-parse/-/lcov-parse-0.0.6.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/request/-/request-2.67.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/log-driver/-/log-driver-1.2.4.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/js-yaml/-/js-yaml-3.0.1.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bl
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/caseless
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/forever-agent
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/extend
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/form-data
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime-types
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/json-stringify-safe
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tunnel-agent
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-uuid
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tough-cookie
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/http-signature
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/qs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/hawk
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/aws-sign2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/oauth-sign
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/stringstream
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/combined-stream
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/is-typedarray
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/isstream
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/har-validator
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/argparse
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/esprima
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/form-data
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/extend
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/forever-agent
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/caseless
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bl
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime-types
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/json-stringify-safe
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tough-cookie
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/http-signature
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tunnel-agent
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-uuid
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/qs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/qs/-/qs-5.2.0.tgz
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/aws-sign2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/hawk
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/stringstream
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/oauth-sign
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/combined-stream
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/is-typedarray
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/har-validator
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/isstream
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/argparse
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/qs/-/qs-5.2.0.tgz
npm WARN engine hawk@3.1.3: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.32"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.24","npm":"1.3.21"})
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/esprima
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/delayed-stream
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime-db
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/assert-plus
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sshpk
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jsprim
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/chalk
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/commander
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/is-my-json-valid
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pinkie-promise
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore.string
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cryptiles
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/boom
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sntp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/hoek
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/delayed-stream
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime-db
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sshpk
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/assert-plus
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jsprim
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/chalk
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/extsprintf/1.0.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/json-schema/0.2.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/verror/1.3.6
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/core-util-is
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/string_decoder
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/isarray
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/process-nextick-args
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/util-deprecate
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tweetnacl
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/asn1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/dashdash
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jsbn
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jodid25519
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ecc-jsbn
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/commander
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/is-my-json-valid
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/pinkie-promise
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pinkie
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/escape-string-regexp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/strip-ansi
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-styles
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/has-ansi
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/supports-color
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-readlink
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/generate-object-property
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/xtend
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jsonpointer/2.0.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/generate-function
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cryptiles
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/boom
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sntp
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/hoek
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/verror/1.3.6
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/extsprintf/1.0.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/json-schema/0.2.2
npm WARN engine cryptiles@2.0.5: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.40"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.24","npm":"1.3.21"})
npm WARN engine boom@2.10.1: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.40"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.24","npm":"1.3.21"})
npm WARN engine hoek@2.16.3: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.40"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.24","npm":"1.3.21"})
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/core-util-is
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/isarray
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/string_decoder
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/util-deprecate
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/process-nextick-args
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/asn1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tweetnacl
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/dashdash
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jsbn
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ecc-jsbn
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jodid25519
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/strip-ansi
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-styles
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/escape-string-regexp
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/pinkie
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore.string
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/generate-object-property
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/has-ansi
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/supports-color
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-readlink
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-regex
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/color-convert
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/xtend
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/generate-function
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jsonpointer/2.0.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/is-property
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-regex
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/color-convert
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/is-property
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodebot-workshop/node_modules/johnny-five/node_modules/temporal requires es6-shim@'latest' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodebot-workshop/node_modules/johnny-five/node_modules/es6-shim,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.32.0
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodebot-workshop/node_modules/johnny-five/node_modules/galileo-io requires es6-shim@'latest' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodebot-workshop/node_modules/johnny-five/node_modules/es6-shim,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.32.0
mean@1.0.0 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mean
└── coveralls@2.11.8 (lcov-parse@0.0.6, minimist@1.2.0, log-driver@1.2.4, js-yaml@3.0.1, request@2.67.0)
```

I am working on a tutorial which requires me to perform this task as the image shows:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by the following command:

```
npm install -g generator-meanjs
yo meanjs
```

[image]